# Invalid escape sequence Eclipse String error

Tags: eclipse, string, character-encoding

```
                Thanks Karol, it works



            Hi,
    Working on an eclipse project, typing this peace of code
```

> "selector = selector && selector.replace(/.*(?=#[^\s]*$)/, '') \n"+

```
i get this error
```

> Invalid escape sequence (valid ones are \b \t \n \f \r \" \' \ )

```
          Any idea ?
```

Comment: off the top of my head I'd say you're using invalid character... I see a backslash "s".. maybe its reading that. Though please do include some more detail as to the copntext of your code and what you're tryign to accomplish

Answer (score 0):

You have `\s` in there, it doesn't mean anything. If you want your JavaScript look like:

```
selector = selector && selector.replace(/.(?=#[^\s]$)/, '')
```

your string needs to look like:

```
"selector = selector && selector.replace(/.(?=#[^\\s]$)/, '') \n"
                                                  ^----- note double backslash
```

It's standard Java's backslash escaping.